# Button CSS filter drop-shadow only parent

Tags: html, css, sass, less

Hello guys i need your help

I want to do that: [Model Botton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGthm.png)

The problem is that, when i add a filter

> filter: drop-shadow(3px 4px 0px #0000B8);

to my button the result is: [My Botton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejsOB.png)

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Is a transparent background required?

Comment: why not simply use `box-shadow`?

Comment: No transparent background is not required.
i tried box-shadow it doesn’t look exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing it.

Here are some examples:

```css
.button-1 {
  position: relative;
  color: #ff1800;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 2px solid #ff1800;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.button-1::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #ff1800;
  border-radius: 100px;
  filter: drop-shadow(7px 12px 0px #0000B8);
  z-index: -1;
}

.button-2 {
  color: #ff1800;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 2px solid #ff1800;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 0 -2px white,
    5px 10px 0 0 #0000B8;
}

.button-3 {
  position: relative;
  color: #ff1800;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 2px solid #ff1800;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.button-3::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 4px;
  top: 8px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #0000B8;
  border-radius: 100px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<button class="button-1">
  Become a seller
</button>

<button class="button-2">
  Become a seller
</button>

<button class="button-3">
  Become a seller
</button>
```

Sadly, none of the methods can have a complete transparent background.